# Recovering code after computer crashed while debugging

Tags: visual-studio

I was debugging a program that I made, and then suddenly, my computer crashed.

Now, when I open it, it is blank, even though it has a size of 7 kb, the same size it had before

Is there any way I can get the code back?

*If it matters, it was a `.cpp` file*

Comment: Your only chance will be using a disk editor/recovery tool scanning for (code) text to find your file manually. Then isolate its sections and manually recombine them.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you recommend some useful or good editor/recovery tool. I have looked for, but it seems that they can also be applied to find .jpg or other some image files.

Comment: Thank you very much all the same. I find I can only rewrite it just now. I have download the Ultra Edit, and sadly find that the content have always be changed to 0.